# binary diffs in files causing unusable deserialized object

Tags: serialization, boost, unicode

I have a problem, which is hard to formulate. I have boost serialized object and I need to create the same one. The first object was created on different machine (but with the same architecture).
Code of serialization/deserialization didn't change.

The new object itself is serialized normally. Both of them are deserialized normally too.
The objects are the same exact size. And at most the same at the content.

The objects are the bunch of unicode UTF8 strings (with some additional information).

But with the old object program is working ok, and with the new one - it's not.

The example of binary differences of two serialized files:
[image: bin diff of two objects]

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem (thanks to my colleagues): the problem is that the first file was serialized with program compiled with gcc flag "-funsigned-char" and the second - with the program compiled without it. When this flag is synchronized, the output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The binary serialization archives aren't actually portable yet. See here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/todo.html#portablebinaryarchives

That might include serialization across versions or even builds of the library (as different compiler options might result in different output).

I would suggest to look at the EOS Portable Archive implementation

- http://epa.codeplex.com/

which is available under a permissive license. This promises to implement a truly portable serialization archive format (with a few, documented, limitations).

I hope you don't need to convert, but you can always convert your old archives to text format archives if need be. This should at least give you a 'middle-ground' representation that works on all the versions of your program. [Compression can help](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html) if file sizes grow out of hand with text archives.